# Kafka + Spring Boot woth Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Cant't connect spring boot with kafka broker.

```
2023-10-11 09:39:19.164  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-10-11 09:39:20.118  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-10-11 09:39:20.118  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-10-11 09:39:21.306  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-10-11 09:39:21.306  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

docker-compose with the 3 services(zookeeper,kafka,findTeam(spring))

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}'"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
  findTeam:
    image: dogzy
    expose:
      - "9090"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/cleverDogzyBack?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useTimezone=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=red5PRO@action
      - SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
    ports:
      - 8026:9091
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

spring application.properties configuration

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=my-group-id
```

spring consumer configuration

```
package infili.findTeam.configuration;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group-id");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Here is the spring producer configuration file

```
package infili.findTeam.configuration;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

help me please i want to fix this to move on to some other things. I think that i am doing something wrong with the configuration on the server side(Spring boot)

Comment: You are ignoring your properties. You are setting `localhost:9092` hardcoded. Also if you are using Spring Boot and Spring Kafka you don't need the confguration class as that will all be configured for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum if i delete the entire file about consumer and producer configuration it throws me error while building.Can you help me a little bit more 

Comment: It doesn't throw an error while building, it throws an error while running your tests as you run those outside docker. Either don't do the tests, or have a dedicated test configureation `application-test.properties` which points to `localhost:9092`. Then on your test(s) add `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to have it loiad the correct config.

Comment: @M.Deinum now it throws me this 
```
2023-10-11 11:12:45.109  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 396 : {my-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Comment: Don;t add code etc. as comments as that is totally unreaddable. Apparently you have a test which does something with a non-existing topic.

Comment: I solved it thank you @M.Deinum